# How to modify checksum after making changes in Nokia 215 4G firmware?

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, unpacking, checksum

If I change any character in the firmware file and try to flash it, it will failed. But it will successfully flashed if I changed the string with the same number of character if it's not a function.

After further searching, I found out about the checksum and that in order to flash the custom firmware, you need to calculate it and modify it in the firmware.

This is the firmware:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/ok2c0qodao5fld1/Nokia_215_4G_readed_test.pac/file

I use HxD to read the file.

If I search for checksum, I got some results ->

[image]

Also, I searched for sha ->

[image]

So here, I tried to change `==` with `!=` and also I changed it to `1 == 1` but, It always failed to flash

I am lost. I don't know what to search for or from where to start.

I hope that someone could help me out!

Note: I can provide access to my PC to try the flash tool (nokia tool v0.060 using easybox) and maybe debugging in the phone.

Comment: i can help you, what you need to change?